# SSIS: string(varchar) to date conversion

Tags: ssis

I need to achieve the date format *yyyy-mm-dd* conversion on SSIS

I tried the below code but I keep getting **error:**

```
year and posting_period is a varchar(50) on my source data.
```

Sample data on my source:

**year** = 2014

**posting_period** = always 2 digit

What did I miss in my codes below?

```
(DT_DBDATE)((DT_WSTR,4)year + "-" + (DT_WSTR,2)posting_period + "-" + "01")
```

Comment: `year and posting_period is a varchar(50) on my source data.` isn't an error message. You don't need string conversions if `year` and `posting_period` are strings

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what should be the conversion statement instead?

Comment: It's *far* safer to convert the parts into numbers and use `DateSerial` to construct a date from its parts

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i can't get it and how can i convert it to my needed date format using the derived column

Comment: please put real error message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the variable's data type to datetime; encapsulate the string in parenthesis; and cast it as DT_DATE:

`(DT_DATE)(@[User::Year] + "-" +  @[User::posting_period] + "-01")`

To my knowledge, you cannot specify how the datetime is displayed. So, this will evaluate to MM/DD/YYYY, which is fine. You should not worry how the date is formatted in the database. You should only care about how it is displayed in the reporting tool, which typically allows you to convert or cast the date in many different ways.